# How to get rid of these c++ warnings?

Tags: c++, lua, warnings

```
warning: argument to `int' from `lua_Number'
```

I get these warnings from using the lua_tonumber function. What is the problem?

Comment: Some example code that demonstrates the problem would help...

Comment: Show the line of code that is producing the warning.

Comment: which compiler? but lua tends to generate a large amount of warnings with c++. probably has something to do with lua only operating on doubles and you're passing an int or the other way around.

Comment: Was that the exact text of the warning?

Comment: Was this the entire warning? Was there a 2nd line?

Answer (score 4):

When you want an `int` from a `lua_Number`, use `lua_tointeger`.

Answer (score 3):

From http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_tonumber:

```
lua_Number lua_tonumber (lua_State *L, int index);
```

It wants an int for the 2nd parameter. Your warning says, helpfully, "argument to `int' from`lua_Number'". So you're probably passing in a 'lua_Number' for the 2nd parameter, rather than an int. a 'lua_Number' is a double.

Since it's an index number into Lua's stack, passing a double doesn't make any sense. I would check your code as passing in a lua_Number is probably a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided and spare informations, my answer is this:

lua_Number is a double. So it is complaining about getting converted to an int.

The easiest method to convert it is this:

```
lua_Number a = 3.7;
int b;
b = static_cast<int>(a)
```

However, b will be 3. If you want to round it, you can do something like this:

```
lua_Number a = 3.7;
int b;
b = static_cast<int>(a+0.5)
```

This way you can ensure that every number which has a suffix higher or equal to 0.5 is rounded.

But you need to decide yourself, what kind of solution you want here.

Comment: I've only ever seen code like `reinterpret_cast<int>(a)`. Does it also work with angle brackets like how you wrote it, or was that a typo? (`reinterpret_cast<int><a>`)

Comment: It's a typo. That would be a syntax error.

Comment: Are you sure you want a `<reinterpret_cast>`?  Conversion between numeric types, such as `int` and `double`, shouldn't require a cast at all; the conversion can be done implicitly (`double d = 3.7; int b = d;`).

Comment: @Wallacoloo Sorry for the wrong brackets that was a typo, thanks for pointing out though.

Comment: @scorcher24 : Actually `static_cast` is the correct way to do it, not `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Why not just `int(a)` or `(int)a`?  (Assuming that converting a `lua_Number` to an `int` is the right thing to do in the first place.)

Comment: @ildjarn Oh God, I am so dumb. okay time for bed. it is late. Changed it though, do not rate it up >_>.

Answer (score -1):

Try static_cast? It usually suppresses warnings, but I'm not familiar with Lua.

Comment: And it usually _masks_ code problems.

Comment: It reeeeally depends on the circumstances. When the warning is just about loss of precision, static_cast is more than acceptable.

Comment: Fixing the loss of precision is more acceptable.